# xlsm into sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, ssis, xlsm

I have an xlsm file with macros that enable data collection from OLE DB source. I just need to make an import package with it in sql server. But when I'm trying to use import/export wizard or ssis-it shows that it can not deal with .xlsm extentions.
Is there any way to deal with it?

Comment: Why are you using Excel macros to pull data instead of using SSIS to pull the data from the OLEDB sources? An `xlsm` file needs an Excel installation to run the macros so it's not the best format for transferring data (to put it mildly).

Comment: because we use remote connection with one server and local machine with another. so it's the only way to deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this :
1-Create an Excel Connection Manager to refer to ANY other spreadsheet with a "valid" XLS or XLSX extension.  (You don't have to save your XLSM file "as" an XLSX.)
2-Select the Excel Connection Manager in your Connection Managers pane.
3-Open the Properties Window (F4).
4-Change the "Server Name" property to the full pathname of your XLSM file.

note: **check the file should not be in read only mode**

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue (SQL Server 2008 R2), Rahul's solution worked for me, but I just want to add a couple of things:

- Select **Excel 2007** in Excel version when creating Excel Connection.
- Use **SQL Command** as Data access mode when editing the Excel Source. Visual Studio crashed for me every time I was trying to use **Table or view**.